# Build failing on Teamcity

Tags: asp.net, .net, build, msbuild, teamcity

Trying to set up a build on Teamcity, never done this before so I haven't a clue what I'm at.  It fails with the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2659,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Can anybody help me with this?  What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you are using .net core build command which does not support this target.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062203/net-core-error-on-build-error-msb4062-microsoft-build-tasks-resolvecomreferenc) is a workaround or just use MSBuild for VS2017. Here is a related thread about the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9558